# Union all on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There has to be a better way of doing this  any one have an idea. there is one table and i have 8 columns i need select all of the columns one on top of each other and for each selected colum i need to count the number of items that are the same

```
SELECT  Col1, count(*) 'Selected'
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col1
UNION ALL
SELECT    Col2,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col2
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col2)))<>0
UNION ALL
SELECT    Col3,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col3
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col3)))<>0
union all
SELECT    Col4,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col4
union all
SELECT    Col5,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col5
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col5)))<>0
union all
SELECT    Col6,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col6
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col6)))<>0
union all
SELECT    Col7,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col7
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col7)))<>0
union all
SELECT    Col8,count(*)
FROM  [Table]  
group by temp_id,Col8
having   len(ltrim(rtrim(Col8)))<>0
```

Comment: Hard to say if there is a better way because it's not clear what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Naming you table [Table] is poor design, as are columns named "col" etc. Also, not sure how this runs as temp_id is never contained in any of the select lists and yet you are aggregating over it?

Comment: Add to your question table structure, sample data and desired output.

Comment: What are your `and`s part of?

Comment: Naming you table [Table] is poor design as are columns named "col" ..... really if i put the actual query up there you definitely would not understand it you cant even understand the dumb down version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is.  It is called grouping sets (and it is documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).  In your case, you can do something like this (example for first three columns):

```
select coalesce(col1, col2, col3), count(*) as Selected
from [table]
group by grouping sets ((temp_id, col1), (temp_id, col2), (temp_id, col3));
```

Your condition using `length()` and `trim()` on each column -- you should probably handle that using a `having` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at the problem before just saying that you don't understand the question and marking it down.

Comment: Just in case anyone else looks at this this only works for 2008 and above